# Will providing more information make independent events dependent?

Tags: probability

Suppose events $X,Y$ are independent given event $Z$, i.e. 
$\Bbb P(X\bigcap Y|Z)=\Bbb P(X|Z)\Bbb P(Y|Z)$, then is it true that $X,Y$ are still independent given any "new information"? i.e. Let $W$ be an arbitrary fourth event, is it still true that 
$\Bbb P(X\bigcap Y|Z\bigcap W)=\Bbb P(X|Z\bigcap W)\Bbb P(Y|Z\bigcap W)$? Thank you! Any proof or counter example will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider two independent dice rolls and $X$ is the event "the first dice shows a 6" and $Y$ "the second dice shows a 6", $Z$ is the trivial event (example "dice have been rolled") but $W$ is "the two dice show the same number".
The two dice rolls are clearly independent, however, knowing that both have the same result doesn't keep the independence.